# How to get data from HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, autocomplete

I use django-autocomplete. There are 2 fields: the first is for tag-search that uses autocomplete and the second is for full-text search. Full-text search works, but tag search not.

Here is code of the web-page:

```
<div class="content-section-a">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form action="" method="get">
          <p>
            <span id="id_tag_query-wrapper" class=" autocomplete-light-widget tag_query single" data-widget-bootstrap="normal" data-widget-maximum-values="1" data-widget-ready="1">
              <span id="id_tag_query-deck" class="deck" style="display: inline;">
                <span data-value="12" class="hilight">
                  <span style="display: inline-block;" class="remove">
                    ˣ
                  </span>
                  Android
                </span>
              </span>
              <input type="text" name="tag_query-autocomplete" id="id_tag_query-autocomplete" value="" class="form-control autocomplete vTextField" data-autocomplete-choice-selector="[data-value]" data-autocomplete-url="/autocomplete/TagAutocomplete/" placeholder="Tag search" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
              <select style="display:none" class="value-select" name="tag_query" id="id_tag_query" multiple="multiple">
                <option selected="selected" value="12"></option></select>
                <span style="display:none" class="remove">ˣ</span>
                <span style="display:none" class="choice-template">
                  <span class="choice prepend-remove append-option-html"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </p>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search"> Search </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

View:

```
class ThreadsView(ListView):
    model = Thread

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TagForm(request.GET)
        if request.GET.get('search'):
            search_results = watson.search(request.GET.get('search'))
            threads = []
            for i in search_results:
                threads.append(i)
            c = RequestContext(request, {'search_list': threads})
            if request.GET.get('id_tag_query-deck'):
                search_results = watson.search(request.GET.get('id_tag_query-deck'))
                threads = []
                for i in search_results:
                    threads.append(i)
                c = RequestContext(request, {'search_list': threads})
            else:
                threads = Thread.objects.all()
                c = RequestContext(request, {'threads_list': threads,
                                             'form': form})
            return render_to_response('threads.html', context_instance=c)
```

Form:

```
class TagForm(forms.Form):
    tag_query = autocomplete_light.fields.ChoiceField(
        choices=(tuple((tag.name, tag.name) for tag in Tag.objects.all())),
        required=False,
        label='',
        widget=autocomplete_light.widgets.ChoiceWidget(
            'TagAutocomplete',
            attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder':'Tag search'
            }
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.GET.get('id_tag_query-deck'):` is false, you need to use the `name` attribute of an input, you are passing the `id` attribute of a `span`

Perhaps

`request.GET.get('tag_query-autocomplete')` or `request.GET.get('tag_query')` will give you the value you want -- depends on which field you want.  Use the `name` of the `input` that you are looking for.